# load collection using annotations @Loader and @NamedQuery Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, polymorphism

I'm trying to load a collection using the **@Loader** annotation and **@NamedQuery** and does not work. If I use **@NamedNativeQuery** if it works, I need to use **@NamedQuery** because the query I use this in HQL. The query uses polymorphism therefore I have no other option than using **@NamedQuery**.

Code:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "loadFacade", query = "FROM Facade WHERE contact_id = ?")
@Table(name = "Contact")
public class Contact extends Atom {

   @OneToMany
   @Loader(namedQuery = "loadFacade")
   @JoinColumn(name = "atom_id")
   private List<Atom> facades;

}
```

this configuration always throws the error:

**Named SQL query not known: loadFacade**

¿ Is possible use annotation @Loader with @NamedQuery annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

You must be really lucky if you could get away with using **NamedQuery** in **@Loader**. [Here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2989) is another issue regarding this in the **open** status in **Hibernate JIRA**.